# importing XML data in Oracle DB (ORACLE_LOADER)

Tags: xml, oracle, loader

I'm new in DBAdministration and I have been asked to design the db structure starting from big (8Gb) xml files.

I'm testing the importing of the data from the XML into the tables, but I cannot fill more than one field at time. For the others I get null results.

Here the code:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(d_name     CHAR(100),
 f_name     CHAR(100),
 w       CHAR(100))

ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY DIR
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
   RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
   NOBADFILE NODISCARDFILE NOLOGFILE
   FIELDS MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL        


   REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
            (
            d_name      CHAR(100) ENCLOSED BY '<d_name>' AND '</d_name>',
            f_name         CHAR(100) ENCLOSED BY '<f_name>' AND '</f_name>',
            w      CHAR(100) ENCLOSED BY '<w>' AND '</w>'
            )
    )
  LOCATION ('xmlFILE.xml')
 )
   reject limit unlimited;
```

Here what I get:

```
d_name|f_name|w
John|null|null
Peter|null|null
```

Can anybody help me to understand where is the mistake?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT** 
the XML starts like this:

```
<REC r_id_disclaimer="">
<UID>yyyyyyyyy</UID>
<static_data>
<summary>
<EWUID>
<WUID coll_id="WOS"/>
<edition value="WOS.AHCI"/>
</EWUID>
<pub_info coverdate="DEC 7 2014" has_abstract="N" issue="49" pubmonth="DEC 7" pubtype="Journal" pubyear="2014" sortdate="2014-12-07" special_issue="SI" vol="119">
<page begin="59" end="59" page_count="1">59-59</page>
</pub_info>
<titles count="1">
<title type="source">Title</title>
</titles>
<names count="2">
<name role="author" seq_no="1">
<d_name>John</d_name>
<f_name>John, RICHARD </f_name>
<w>jOHN, MI</w>
</name>
<name role="author" seq_no="2">
<d_name>Peter</d_name>
<f_name>Peter, RICHARD </f_name>
<w>Pet, MI</w>
</name>
</names>
```

Comment: Showing the content of `xmlFILE.xml` might be helpful for context. Why aren't you loading the data as an XMLType, and then extracting the contents as relational data using the built-in tools?

Comment: Dear Alex, could you give me more information about the built-in tool? As my first try I was using the XMLTYPE, but without success... please see the other topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409638/importing-xml-data-in-oracle-db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields are in different physical records, because of the newlines. With SQL*Loader you can `concatenate` or `continueif` to assemble logical records from physical records, but I don't think the external table driver supports that. Or loading XMLType directly.

You could load it via a CLOB field. Create a data file in the same `DIR` directory which has the real XML file name in it: say `xmlfiles.txt` which just contains the value `xmlFILE.xml` (but could have multiple rows, each referring to a different XML file). Then your external table would be:

```
create table test (xml_clob clob)
organization external
(
  type oracle_loader
  default directory dir
  access parameters
  (
    records delimited by newline
    nobadfile nodiscardfile nologfile
    fields missing field values are null        
    reject rows with all null fields
    (
      xml_filename char(80)
    )
    column transforms (xml_clob from lobfile (xml_filename) from (dir) clob)
  )
  location ('xmlfiles.txt')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

Notice that the `location` is now the new file containing the real file's name; and [the `column transforms` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1440) is using the real file name - from the `xml_filename` extracted from the new file - to actually load the CLOB data. You can't have a CLOB directly in the loader data file, it has to be in a separate file that is referenced.

The `test` table now has that XML file stored as a CLOB, and you can convert it to an XMLType to manipulate it, e.g. as part of [an XMLTable clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm):

```
select x.*
from test t
cross join xmltable('/REC/static_data/summary/names/name'
  passing xmltype(t.xml_clob)
  columns d_name varchar2(20) path 'd_name',
    f_name varchar2(20) path 'f_name',
    w varchar2(20) path 'w'
) x;

D_NAME               F_NAME               W                  
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
John                 John, RICHARD        jOHN, MI            
Peter                Peter, RICHARD       Pet, MI
```

The `xmltype(t.xml_clob)` is doing the conversion, so the XPath is applied to an XML document formed from the CLOB value in the table.

---

There is a section of the documentation that addresses [loading XML content](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb03usg.htm#ADXDB4048). If you get it into the DB as XML then you can manipulate it to create relational data.

Using the mechanism you tried in your previous question, and repeating *some* parts of that answer, you can create the staging table with an XMLType column and load from a bfile:

```
create table test (xml_file xmltype)
xmltype xml_file store as securefile binary xml;

insert into test (xml_file) 
select xmltype(bfilename('DIR', 'xmlFILE.xml'), nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1'))
from dual;
```

You can then use an XMLTable clause again to get the data in a relational form:

```
select x.*
from test t
cross join xmltable('/REC/static_data/summary/names/name'
  passing t.xml_file 
  columns seq_no number path '@seq_no',
    d_name varchar2(20) path 'd_name',
    f_name varchar2(20) path 'f_name',
    w varchar2(20) path 'w'
) x;

    SEQ_NO D_NAME               F_NAME               W                  
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 John                 John, RICHARD        jOHN, MI            
         2 Peter                Peter, RICHARD       Pet, MI
```

I've included the `seq_no` just to show how to get an attribute value.

The XPath has to match your real file; I added the closing tags for summary, static_data and REC to make it valid, but if you also have an enclosing `records` level (as shown in the previous question) then you'd need to include that in the XPath, and also specify the namespace:

```
...
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  '/records/REC/static_data/summary/names/name'
  passing t.xml_file
...
```

---

If you want to get data from two levels you can pull it out as shown in your comment, but not if any of the child nodes are repeated; here you have more then one name for each `REC`, so you'd get `ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence`. You could use FLWOR syntax go create new elements combining the data, but it might be simpler to extract the `names` node and pass that to a second XMLTable:

```
select x.cd_uid, y.*
from test t
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  '/records/REC'
  passing t.xml_file 
  columns cd_uid varchar2(10) path 'UID',
    names xmltype path 'static_data/summary/names'
) x
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  'names/name'
  passing x.names 
  columns seq_no number path '@seq_no',
    d_name varchar2(20) path 'd_name',
    f_name varchar2(20) path 'f_name',
    w varchar2(20) path 'w'
) y;

CD_UID         SEQ_NO D_NAME               F_NAME               W                  
---------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
yyyyyyyyy           1 John                 John, RICHARD        jOHN, MI            
yyyyyyyyy           2 Peter                Peter, RICHARD       Pet, MI
```

The `names` sub-XML is extracted as `x.names`, and the individual elements are then pulled out of that in the `y` XMLTable. You can do that for multiple levels if necessary, and pull a mix of singleton and sequence data out of each, depending how complicated your XML structure is.

Comment: Thank you Alex,very helpful!
I'm tryng to"merge"different fields that are in different paths,but I get null values.
'   select x.*
   from testtable2 t
    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
     'records/REC'
      passing t.xml_file 
      columns 
        cd_uid varchar2(200) path 'UID',
        d_name varchar2(200) path '/static_data/summary/names/name/d_name',
        f_name varchar2(200) path '/static_data/summary/names/name/f_name',
        w varchar2(200) path '/static_data/summary/names/name/w'
    ) x;'

Comment: @newinIT - that would sort of work if you removed the `/` in front of the path starting `/static_data/...`; but then you'd get an ORA-19279 error. I've updated the answer with an example of how to nest XMLTable calls to get the related data out together.

Comment: And what about the correct code to show "Title" and "Title2" in case of <title type="source">Title</title><title type="item">Title2</title>? I've tried the below code `LB_TITLE_SOURCE varchar2(20) path '@type=source' ` but I get "true" or "false" results. Thanks!

Comment: @newinIT - you need the full path from REC down to the title; and you need to filter on the type value: `lb_title_source varchar2(20) path 'static_data/summary/titles/title[@type="source"]'`, which with your sample gives a result of `Title`.

Comment: @newinIT - you're getting a long way from your original issue; you should ask a new question if you have further problems getting the XPath right for the data you need (referring back to this for context if it's relevant). (And preferably [mark this question as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), though that's up to you!)